# Read words from paragraph to paragraph, from line to line (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a way to read and locate words (line number, paragraph number) from a file.

For example, I want to track the number of the word "you" in a file. Each time I find this word on a line, I will push the line number and the paragraph number to the two vectors

```
ifstream file;
file.open(input.txt)
vector<int> paragraph_number;
vector<int> line_number;
```

What's the best way to read paragraph by paragraph and line by line? Thank you!

Comment: Depends on how you define a 'paragraph'.

Comment: @vahancho: There's a line space between paragraphs

Comment: @PemiNg a space ? but there is also a space between words no ? Do you mean newline after each paragraph ? Or may be a dot ?

Comment: @bruno: I mean two newline space

Answer (score 4):

Line number is fairly simple, as you can just use `getline` or something similar to read one line at a time. Just keep track of the number of times you read a line from the file. Or, you could count the number of newline (`\n`) you run across.

Paragraph is a bit trickier, there's no standardized way to look at paragraph in a file. You would probably need some sort of character delimiter for the end of a paragraph. You could interpret two newlines as a new paragraph, but that part is up to you.

Comment: Yes my .txt is pretty standard, so two newline is good. Would you mind telling me the code for this? I'll really appreciate it

Comment: That I'm going to leave up to you. However, do know that a newline can be recognized just like any other ASCII character.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing

- paragraphs are separated by at least one empty line, so a line just containing a newline
- a line even with only spaces is not an empty line, but that has no real sense and I let you changing that ;-)
- the program memorizes the number of paragraph line and column where the word appears, all these numbers start by 1, and the line number is global rather than the line rank into the paragraph
- a word only contains alphanumeric character, so all other characters are considered to be a separator. That allows to find the word "isn" or "t" in "this isn't possible" even they are not separated by a space with the other words, or to find "jean" in "jean-luc" etc
- the program does not check if the input word is a valid word

A proposal  :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 3)
      std::cerr << "Usage: " << *argv << " <file path> <word>" << std::endl;
  else {
    std::ifstream f(argv[1]);

    if (! f.is_open())
      std::cerr << "Cannot open '" << argv[1] << '\'' << std::endl;
    else {
      std::string word = argv[2];
      std::string line;
      size_t line_num = 0;
      size_t paragraph_num = 0;
      std::vector<size_t> paragraph_number; 
      std::vector<size_t> line_number;
      std::vector<size_t> column_number;
      bool afterEmptyLine = true;

      while (std::getline(f, line)) {
        line_num += 1;
        if (!line.empty()) {
          if (afterEmptyLine) {
            afterEmptyLine = false;
            paragraph_num += 1;
          }

          std::size_t p = 0;

          while ((p = line.find(word, p)) != std::string::npos) {
            // check it is not a subword, suppose a word is only alphanum
            if (((p == 0) || !isalnum(line[p - 1])) &&
                ((line.length() == (p + word.length())) || !isalnum(line[p + word.length()]))) {
              paragraph_number.push_back(paragraph_num);
              line_number.push_back(line_num);
              column_number.push_back(p + 1);
            }

            p += word.length();
          }
        }
        else
          afterEmptyLine = true;
      }

      /* debug */
      std::cout << '\'' << word << "' found " << paragraph_number.size() << " times :" << std::endl;

      for (size_t i = 0; i != paragraph_number.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "\t paragraph " << paragraph_number[i] 
          << " line " << line_number[i]
            << " column " << column_number[i] << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.cc
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ cat fw
is it you or not you?
this is your decision and you are right

you and me



you
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ ./a.out
Usage: ./a.out <file path> <word>
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ ./a.out fw you
'you' found 5 times :
     paragraph 1 line 1 column 7
     paragraph 1 line 1 column 18
     paragraph 1 line 2 column 27
     paragraph 2 line 4 column 1
     paragraph 3 line 8 column 1
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$
```

(in the file the empty lines are really empty)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
ifstream file("input.txt");

vector<int> paragraph_number;
vector<int> line_number;
string line, word;
int curr_paragraph_num = 0;
int curr_line_num = 0;
bool in_paragraph = false;

while (getline(file, line))
{
    ++curr_line_num;
    if (line.empty())
    {
        in_paragraph = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!in_paragraph)
        {
            in_paragraph = true;
            ++curr_paragraph_num;
        }

        istringstream iss(line);
        while (iss >> word)
        {
            if (word == "you")
            {
                paragraph_number.push_back(curr_paragraph_num);
                line_number.push_back(curr_line_num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```